# PLS 00306 Error PL/SQL

Tags: database, plsql

I use SQL *PLUS to run this code

```
DECLARE
v_sal NUMBER:= 3000;
v_valid BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
v_valid := v_sal BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value of v_valid is ' || v_valid);
END;
/
```

I read that I can use this expression to assign boolean value.
Why then I get this error @ line 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the problem is the BETWEEN expression. It's the DBMS_OUTPUT line. It can't handle BOOLEAN values. The following code works:

```
set serveroutput on

DECLARE
  v_sal NUMBER:= 3000;
  v_valid BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  v_valid := v_sal BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000;
  dbms_output.put_line(CASE WHEN v_valid THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END);
END;
/
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to include a `null` checking condition in the `CASE` expression, because if `v_sal` happens to be `NULL`, `v_valid` is also `NULL` and `CASE` expression will give us `false`, which is  wrong answer.